# Tradeoffs of browser-based development vs. Smart Client

Tags: browser, architecture, client

I've got an app that's been started on the Microsoft stack as a smart client (notionally WCF/WS enabled) with a small client app that gets deployed and the rest of the app running in our private cloud.  It's only real dependency is internet connectivity, .net 4 and a windows operating system.

I am under pressure to convert over to a browser based architecture for all future development.  Based on other web apps I've worked on, I'm concerned that the way that client IT organizations can control the browser, it will cause more problems down the line than what I really want to deal with.

Do you have experience making this kind of decision?  What technical factors did you consider when deciding to go smart-client vs. browser?  What resources were helpful in making this decision?

My app is a healthcare app targeted at healthcare providers (eg. hospitals), so everywhere I go, I have to worry about the Healthcare CIO looking over my shoulder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting. Originally I'm from C# winform and WPF Desktop programmer, and later being assigned to do web development. Haven't touch Smart Client yet but I think it should almost be the same with Native app. Based on experience, the technical things to consider are:

1. Multi browser support

   Especially for reporting and graphic processing, without some library / plugins / framework for your component, it will be insanely hard to keep your app multibrowser. Especially in css style and less in javascript.
2. Client programming(javascript)

   You will lose the ability to create controls and animation using C# controls. Instead you must using javascript (jquery or other library) in exchange. Javascript is not fully OOP, and intepret language (no compile error), making it harder (maybe there is some framework like coffeeScript which I haven't yet explore). In addition, it is harder to make since it will need server request / response activity in between the process, which I will describe later.
3. Request / Response Client-Server Architecture

   This means that most process in client will need to request for the server (request for data to display, request to modify the data, etc). It also means that you lose the ability of control event, even if you use asp.net webform (it still need some tweaks for the event to work). However I assume you already used the WCF so this kind of architecture must be that hard.
4. Security

   Don't keep important information such as password, etc in client (hidden field, javascript variable, etc). The concept should be the same with multitenant client, however in browser, user has free access to debug your webpage.
5. Concurrent and Multithreading

   In browser, it is easier for multitab page and concurrent process will be very highly to occur. Your code must able to handle the multi threading for client side. For server side, you can still use your WCF to handle concurrencies.

My 2 cents.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the web application has its own challenges. I hope this link can help you in some aspects: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658099.aspx

Along with those you need to focus on non-function requirements like extensibility and scalability etc. too.